# laravel paypal payment intergration

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

laravel composer.json file add the require

```
"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*"
```

after that i update composer then route.php file is

```
 Route::get('payment', 'PaypalPaymentController@getPaymentStatus');
```

PaypalPaymentController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

class PaypalPaymentController extends Controller
{   
    private $_apiContext;
    public function __construct()
    {
        // setup PayPal api context
        $paypal_conf = Config::get('paypal_payment');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']));
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
   }
    public function getPaymentStatus()
    { echo "success";exit;
    }
}
```

paypal_payment.php

```
<?php

return array(
    // set your paypal credential
    'client_id' => 'AU7H2ny1QyVJCgkb2-fashll2vi2TzzomIoR_xU5NhHoxdOsqZ9WIX5yxRZsi0qUvQ-NS2u4dWvwcmIm',
    'secret' => 'ENDTVkcg9qV1cKUjb3zVtlZpzkdf4do-ogOxOEpUa25AGljctawwCcCZphN8PmJfIcWbgEvvSuOlOZ41',

    /**
     * SDK configuration 
     */
    'settings' => array(
        /**
         * Available option 'sandbox' or 'live'
         */
        'mode' => 'sandbox',

        /**
         * Specify the max request time in seconds
         */
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,

        /**
         * Whether want to log to a file
         */
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,

        /**
         * Specify the file that want to write on
         */
        'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',

        /**
         * Available option 'FINE', 'INFO', 'WARN' or 'ERROR'
         *
         * Logging is most verbose in the 'FINE' level and decreases as you
         * proceed towards ERROR
         */
        'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
    ),
);
```

But i am getting status code: (500 Internal server error) in my console

i am new in laravel paypalment. what is mistake of my code need to update app.php file????

Comment: What's the error? It shows if you inspect the XHR request in the network tab under response (but preview is better for html) chrome of course.

Comment: In html i am getting Whoops, looks like something went wrong. error  for chrome browser

Comment: Then you need to check your `laravel.log` file.